# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt (add_library):

Tags: cmake

I wan't to compile an external library:

It works with the complete path of the source like:

```
add_library(timetool   "../src/wnt/foo.cxx"
                       "../../../../include/foo.h"
```

It DOESN'T works

```
add_library(timetool   "../src/wnt/*.cxx"
                       "../../../../include/*.h"
```

And I get the error message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:25 (add_library):
Cannot find source file:

../src/*.cxx

Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx
```

What can I do to solve the Problem?

Comment: @ Florian: Thanks, you going right "no whildcards in the function `add_library`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And that is the solution! No whildcards in function `add_library`

```
file(GLOB timetool_SRC   "../src/wnt/*.cxx"
                         "../../../../include/*.h"

add_library(timetool ${timetool_SRC}
```

Comment: You should change add_library(timetool ${timetool_SRC} to add_library(timetool ${timetool_SRC}) you forgot ')'.